# Vertical centering in absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have absolute positioned div and I have to vertically center his content. Any solution?

**Update:**
My content is rotated (by css3) image and this image is already horizontal positioned.

```
  <div style="width:200px;height:100px;background:black;position:absolute;">
        <img src="a.png" style="width:100px;-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; display:block"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to give more details about the content. Is it a single line of text? Do you know the height of the content? Or that of the container?

Answer (score 0):

`dh = your div's height`
`yourDiv.style.top = window.innerHeight/2-dh/2`

this is max you are going to go get without details.

**Edit**: after knowing that content is image.

**first** way, if you know both the heights, `div`'s and `img`'s already.

```
 <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:black;position:absolute;">
        <img src="a.png" style="width:100px;-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; display:block"/>
    </div>​
```

and style for image

```
img{margin-top:23%;}​
```

fiddle to go with it: http://jsfiddle.net/DZBp8/

**second** way: some jQuery, as I already answered.
html:
     
            
        ​
jQuery:

```
var dh = $('#container').height();
var ih = $('img').height();
$('img').css('margin-top',(dh-ih)/2+'px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DZBp8/1/

Comment: added details. please let me know if this won't do. nothing I like on friday nights better than finding solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
 <!-- This method is for for modern browsers only -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Vertical Centering</title>
<style>
.parent {
  display: table;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<div class="content">
      This content will be vertically centered in the parent element.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See [Working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7EmV/)  . You can work around it and get your solution . Hope this helps.